Unit testing overloaded python methods
I'm trying to unit-test some overloaded Python methods, in an attempt to increase the overall coverage of my code. Here are the overloaded methods, and the main method that is associated with them:
@overload
def __setitem__(self, index: int, value: Cup) -> None:
    ...

@overload
def __setitem__(self, index: slice, value: Iterable[Cup]) -> None:
    ...

def __setitem__(self, index: int | slice,
                value: Cup | Iterable[Cup]) -> None:
    if isinstance(index, int):
        if not isinstance(value, Cup):
            raise TypeError("Expected item of type Cup" +
                            "got {}".format(type(value).__name__))
        self.cups[index] = value
    elif isinstance(index, slice):
        # Check that value is iterable and consists only of Cup instances
        if isinstance(value, Iterable) and all(isinstance
                                               (item, Cup)
                                               for item in value):
            self.cups[index] = list(value)
        else:
            raise TypeError("Expected Iterable of Cups")

I've tried to test them by having a test case that calls the main method associated with the overloaded methods. Here is the test case that I wrote:
def test_setitem_with_int(self):
    cup_list = Cup_List()
    cup = Cup("red 10")
    cup_list.append(cup)
    index_int = 0
    cup_list.__setitem__(index_int, cup)

I thought that calling the main method would indirectly call the overloaded methods. However, this does not appear to be the case. Does anyone know what I can do with my test case, so that it covers the overloaded methods?

Overloads like you show are only used for static typing. They don't exist at runtime (the undecorated def __setitem__ overwrites them). If you're trying to test each branch of your implementation, just try doing an assignments like cup_list[0] = cup and cup_list[0:] = [cup] (you can also test invalid assignments and verify you get the expected exceptions if you want).

So, is unit testing overload methods such as the ones I provided above impossible? I have done tests with assignment and exceptions. I'm just trying to see if the overloaded methods can be tested, as I'm trying to maximize my test coverage and they're one of few things that I don't have tests for.

There is no way of calling the @overload decorated stubs at run time. Nor do they do anything, as should be obvious from the ... body of each function. So there's not really anything to test! Run static type checking and you'll have gotten the only possible use out of them.
